# What is use of attach() method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

i dont have a idea what is use of this method i saw something on someone code like this.

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

$new_car = new Car();
$new_car->name = $request->name;
$new_car->age = $request->age;
$new_car->model = $request->model;
$new_car->save();

$time = new Reservation();
$time->from_date = $request->from_date;
$time->to_date = $request->to_date;
$time->from_time= $request->from_time;
$time->to_time = $request->to_time;
$time->save();

// Attach the reservation to the car's reservations
$new_car->Reservation()->attach($time->id);

// Attach the car to the user cars
$user->cars()->attach($new_car->id);
```

hopefully someone can explain me well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Attaching / Detaching**

Attach is used mainly **Eloquent Relationship** in **Many To Many Relationships**. It mainly uses intermediate table data insert or update. For example, let's imagine a user can have many roles and a role can have many users. You may use the attach method to attach a role to a user by inserting a record in the relationship's intermediate table:

[For more details](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)